# ng test - unexpected token 'const'

Tags: unit-testing, angular, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've created an application using `angular-cli`. Now I'm trying to run some unit tests but instead of Chrome I want to run them with PhantomJS. So I changed my `package.json` to look like:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start-lite": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\"",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "angular2-wizard": "^0.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "video.js": "^5.17.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

---

### Karma configuration

`karma.conf.js` ->

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

---

### Error

But now the problem is that, every time I run a test I get an error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
  at webpack:///src/app/app.component.ts:1:0 <- src/test.ts:63183

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
  at webpack:///src/app/app.component.ts:1:0 <- src/test.ts:63183
```

If neccessary I can provide `src/test.ts` but it's just a basic unit test. I've looked through all my files and replaced the `const` with `var`. Sadly this didn't solve anything.

---

Questions I've looked into but didn't help finding a solution:

- [SyntaxError: Unexpected token const { in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857215/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-const-in-node-js)
- [SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' (with Vue, Karma, Webpack, PhantomJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747123/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-const-with-vue-karma-webpack-phantomjs)
- [Unexpected Token after const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801480/unexpected-token-after-const)
- [SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' for testing.es5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513591/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-const-for-testing-es5-js)
- [Running "ng" causes "Unexpected token ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923239/running-ng-causes-unexpected-token)

Comment: Try a newer Phantomjs, currently 2.5 beta, that fully supports ES6: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out changing `es6` to `es5` in `src/tsconfig.spec.json` solved the issue.

(thought I only had 1 `tsconfig.json`, never worked with `angular/cli` before.